# Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.Ci

Tags: codeigniter

I had done image upload,resized many times in CI. The same code is working in one page but not working in other page . when i display the error it says" Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."  The code to upload image is ...\

```
 function do_upload() {

        $original_path = './uploads/activity_images/original';
        $resized_path = './uploads/activity_images/resized';
        $thumbs_path = './uploads/activity_images/thumb';
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', //only accept these file types
            'max_size' => 2048, //2MB max
            'upload_path' => $original_path //upload directory    
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image
        $image1 = $image_data['file_name'];

        //your desired config for the resize() function
        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
            'new_image' => $resized_path,
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 128,
            'height' => 128
        );
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        // for the Thumbnail image
        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $thumbs_path,
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 36,
            'height' => 36
        );
        //here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        $this->image_lib->resize();
        //$this->image_lib->clear();
       echo  $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        var_dump(gd_info());
        die();
        return $image1;
    }
```

What is going on i can't understand..??

Comment: What does `var_dump(gd_info());` gives you?

Comment: array
  'GD Version' => string 'bundled (2.0.34 compatible)' (length=27)
  'FreeType Support' => boolean true
  'FreeType Linkage' => string 'with freetype' (length=13)
  'T1Lib Support' => boolean false
  'GIF Read Support' => boolean true
  'GIF Create Support' => boolean true
  'JPEG Support' => boolean true
  'PNG Support' => boolean true
  'WBMP Support' => boolean true
  'XPM Support' => boolean false
  'XBM Support' => boolean true
  'JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support' => boolean false

Comment: Also do you have `$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your first lines from:

```
$original_path = './uploads/activity_images/original';
$resized_path = './uploads/activity_images/resized';
$thumbs_path = './uploads/activity_images/thumb';
$this->load->library('image_lib');
```

to:

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$original_path = './uploads/activity_images/original';
$resized_path = './uploads/activity_images/resized';
$thumbs_path = './uploads/activity_images/thumb';
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Comment: Hm. Okay, great you fixed it.

Comment: I just discovered myself that CI throws this error if you don't provide a full path to a valid image file. If the filename is missing for example then getimagesize() returns false and that leads to the error. Not very clear ...

Answer (score 13):

During my project I faced similar problem. This [link](http://philonthe.net/2010/07/codeigniters-image-library/) help me to solve it.

Replace

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

with

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
// Set your config up
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// Do your manipulation
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had all of the above set still I was shown

> "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."

I went through some research to re-installed or fixed the installation of the `php-gd` library.
You can do this by issuing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

and once done, I have restarted apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It worked perfectly.

You can change `php7.1-gd` based on your PHP version installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works (my case), the error might actually be the whole issue.

1. Check if you have gd installed, on linux you would do

   sudo yum list installed | grep php
2. If not installed, install it

   sudo yum install php-gd-package-name
3. RESTART your apache

   sudo service httpd restart