# Getting error "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image." when resizing in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter To upload as well as resize images. Using library image_lib and loading it in the following way. My upload is working fine but having problem with the php gd function. When printing the error it says,
    "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."
I did not have gd enabled. I have restarted my xampp after enabling it. And still have the problem.

```
                //get the image sizes
                $image_sizes = $this->image_model->get_image_sizes();

                foreach ($image_sizes as $image_size) {
                    $this->load->library('image_lib');


                    $mod_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $mod_config['source_image'] = './uploads/';
                    $mod_config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                    $mod_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                    $mod_config['width'] = $image_size->image_size_width;
                    $mod_config['height'] = $image_size->image_size_height;

                    $this->image_lib->initialize($mod_config);

                    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
                    {
                        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();exit;
                    }

                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.Ci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915016/your-server-does-not-support-the-gd-function-required-to-process-this-type-of-im)

Comment: Hey thanks !!! Found it in the comment to the marked solution. But the marked solution is not the answer to my question, so I overlooked it. Anyway, I had to specify the source image path correctly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Demo from Codeigniter Doc with some changes because it is not working in my case:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 75;
$config['height'] = 50;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
} 

$this->image_lib->clear();
```

**Explanation:**

> The above code tells the image_resize function to look for an image
>   called mypic.jpg located in the source_image folder, then create a
>   thumbnail that is 75 X 50 pixels using the GD2 image_library. Since
>   the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the thumb will be as close to
>   the target width and height as possible while preserving the original
>   aspect ratio. The thumbnail will be called mypic_thumb.jpg and located
>   at the same level as source_image.