# upload and resize image with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my code for `upload` and `resize` in codeigniter. Everything is ok with `upload` but `resize` keeps giving me errors:

> Your server does not support GD function to process this image type.

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './gallery/gallery_big/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['max_size'] = '900000 * 50';
    $config['max_width']  = '21024 * 50';
    $config['max_height']  = '21068 * 50';
    $config['remove_spaces']= TRUE;
    $config['upload_url']=site_url()."gallery/gallery_big/";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $field_name ="upfiles";
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
    $file_name =   $upload_data['file_name'];

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
    {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("<?php echo $error; ?>");
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        $success ='File Successfully Uploaded !!';

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">   
                alert("<?php echo $success; ?>");
            </script>
        <?php
    }

    $this->resize_img();
    //$this->resize_img1();
    //$this->resize_img2();
} 

function resize_img()
{
    $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config1['source_image']='./gallery/gallery_big/';
    $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config1['quality'] = 100;
    $config1['new_image']='./gallery/thumbnails/';
    $config1['width']= 100;
    $config1['height']= 100;      

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {        
        $error = $this->image_lib->display_errors();

        ?>  
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("<?php echo $error; ?>");
            </script>
        <?php
    }

    //$this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

Comment: FYI, your `php` tags are reversed.

Comment: You can't use JS code that way in method of your class. Also if you use line `$this->upload->initialize($config);` then there is no need for second parameter in line when library loads.

Comment: Fogot to say,
I am not sure have you googled or searched on SOF so far and what difference was in your issue and found ones, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915016/your-server-does-not-support-the-gd-function-required-to-process-this-type-of-im) could help. I have got it with just simple google search of "Your server does not support GD function to process this image type.".