# Can not insert the data with image upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made insert data along upload images into the database , when the run was successful , but when the insert data and upload images contained errors.

> The path to the image is not correct.
>
> Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

how to cope if I insert the data without uploading images is not error ? and the image database went into default image ?

This my controllers

```
public function save(){   
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    //$nama_asli = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $id = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);

    $config['file_name'] = $id ;//'_'.'_'.$nama_asli;
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
    $config['max_size'] = '100000';
    
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $files = $this->upload->data();
        $fileNameResize = $config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'];
        $size =  array(             
                    array('name'    => 'thumb','width'  => 100, 'height'    => 100, 'quality'   => '100%')
                );
        $resize = array();
        foreach($size as $r){               
            $resize = array(
                "width"         => $r['width'],
                "height"        => $r['height'],
                "quality"       => $r['quality'],
                "source_image"  => $fileNameResize,
                "new_image"     => $url.$r['name'].'/'.$config['file_name']
            );
        $this->image_lib->initialize($resize); 
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())                 
            die($this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }   
        
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());      
        $get_name = $this->upload->data();
        $nama_foto = $get_name['file_name'];
        $this->mcrud->savealat($nama_foto);
        redirect('instrument/detailalat');      
    }
}
```

This my model

```
function savealat($nama_foto) {
    $data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'namaalat' => $this->input->post('namaalat'),
        'dayalistrik' => $this->input->post('dayalistrik'),     
        'merk' => $this->input->post('merk'),
        'namasupplier' => $this->input->post('namasupplier'),       
        'nokatalog' => $this->input->post('nokatalog'),     
        'noseri' => $this->input->post('noseri'),       
        'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'lokasi' => $this->input->post('lokasi'),
        'pengguna' => $this->input->post('pengguna'),
        'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
        'jadwalkal' => $this->input->post('jadwalkal'),     
        'manual' => $this->input->post('manual'),
        'dateinput' => $this->input->post('date'),      
        'foto' => $nama_foto
        //'created' => $tanggal
    );  
    $this->db->insert('tbdetail', $data);
}
```

Comment: But is the image saved into your main directory?

Comment: @LorenzoMagno, if I insert the data and upload photos stored on a directory

Comment: I gave a short code earlier, try it. The cycle would be submit form, then image wouldbe moved to directory, then insert into database. If that doesn't clear up just tag me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public function save(){   
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    //$nama_asli = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $id = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);

    $config['file_name'] = $id ;//'_'.'_'.$nama_asli;
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
    $config['max_size'] = '100000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $files = $this->upload->data();
        $fileNameResize = $config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'];
        $size =  array(             
                    array('name'    => 'thumb','width'  => 100, 'height'    => 100, 'quality'   => '100%')
                );
        $resize = array();
        foreach($size as $r){               
            $resize = array(
                "width"         => $r['width'],
                "height"        => $r['height'],
                "quality"       => $r['quality'],
                "source_image"  => $fileNameResize,
                "new_image"     => base_url().$r['name'].'/'.$config['file_name']
            );
        $this->image_lib->initialize($resize); 
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())                 
            die($this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }   

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());      
        $get_name = $this->upload->data();
        $nama_foto = $get_name['file_name'];
        $this->mcrud->savealat($nama_foto);
        redirect('instrument/detailalat');   


    }
    else
    {   

        //Moved your code up there
    }
}
```

If I'm right the problem is that you put the upload in else. Try to move the code and tell me if it works

Comment: No prob glad to help out

Comment: sorry @Lorenzo Magno, now if I insert the data and upload photos error occurs

Comment: What error does it show? I'll still be here to help

Comment: the error same with my question with `Message: Undefined variable: url Line Number: 174` and this script line 174 `"new_image"     => $url.$r['name'].'/'.$config['file_name']`

Comment: Oyes! I see your error now. You never defined $url, anywhere. What url are you thinking of?

Comment: take a look at what i added to "new_image" line. maybe that can solve it

Comment: the error new_image its solved, but `The path to the image is not correct ` and `Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image` still error.. whereas before with the same script is not error when uploading images

Comment: I know the problems I experienced there in the `$resize` so I delete and everything is normal thanks for all your help .

Answer (score 1):

MaY be this answer can help you out. There are few more suggestion in comment part which can figure some way out for you. [Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.Ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915016/your-server-does-not-support-the-gd-function-required-to-process-this-type-of-im)